# How to open a test page with a url with a certain domain in path without deploying it to a server?

Tags: windows, testing, browser, cookies

This seems like a simple question, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it...

I have a simple html page. All that html page does is looks to see whether a browser cookie is present, and if it is, it will write a message that says "Found the cookie".

In order for this html page to work, it needs to be opened in a browser using a url that uses a specific domain "mytestsite.org" in the path in order to work. So I want to be able to open that page in a browser using a url like "www.mytestsite.org/mytestpage.html". Easy enough...

When I use this test page locally, I just deploy it to a local JBoss server, then make a mapping in my "hosts" file (I'm on Windows XP), that maps my local IP to "local.mytestsite.org". This tricks the browser into thinking that it is actually getting the page from "mytestsite.org", when it is actually being served by my local JBoss server.

I want to give this html file to another person who is going to use it on their pc. However, they don't have any sort of http server installed, so the little host mapping trick won't work. I don't want to make them go through the trouble of installing a server just to get this test page to work. Additionally, I can't physically put this file on "mytestsite.org".

Any thoughts on how I could open this page through a "mytestsite.org" url through a browser, without actually having it deployed to a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your test machine with JBoss installed accessible from the Internet? If so, you may ask the other person to add a mapping to their `hosts` file, that maps `local.mytextsite.org` to the public IP of your test machine.

Comment: Nope, it's not, unfortunately. We are on the same network though... would that make a difference?

Comment: I think it boils down to the question: can the other person access your local JBoss server through the network? That may or may not be the case depending on the security policy in effect on the network.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it is. I had the guy try to hit my local web server directly through my ip and port, but no luck.

Comment: No luck indeed... Is asking the IT people to open port 80 to your machine an option? Otherwise I can't think of any other simple solution.

Comment: Marking this as the answer. The bottom line is that the file MUST be hosted on an http server somewhere... so host the file somewhere on an http server (your own pc if possible, some public hosting service like google apps, the users machine if they install a lightweight http server) and have the user edit their hosts file.